# Do I need to use locking in the following c# code?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

In the following code I am using two threads to share sane resource in this example it's a `queue` so do I need to use `lock` while `en-queueing or dequeuing` if yes then why because program seems to work fine.

```
class Program
{   
    static Queue<string> sQ = new Queue<string>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread prodThread = new Thread(ProduceData);
        Thread consumeThread = new Thread(ConsumeData);
        prodThread.Start();
        consumeThread.Start();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void ProduceData()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            sQ.Enqueue(i.ToString());               
        }
    }

    private static void ConsumeData()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (sQ.Count > 0)
            {
                string s = sQ.Dequeue();
                Console.WriteLine("DEQUEUE::::" + s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do I need to use lock in the following C# code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13998526/do-i-need-to-use-lock-in-the-following-c-sharp-code)

Answer (score 8):

Yes you do, `System.Collections.Generic.Queue<T>` is not thread safe for being written to and read from at the same time. You either need to lock on the same object before enquing or dequing or if you are using .NET 4/4.5 use the `System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue<T>` class instead and use the `TryDequeue` method.

The reason your current implementation has not caused you a problem so far, is due to the `Thread.Sleep(500)` call (not something you should be using in production code) which means that the `prodThread` doesn't write to the queue while the `consumeThread` reads from it since the read operation takes less than 500ms. If you remove the `Thread.Sleep` odds are it will throw an exception at some point.